# How can I get the photo ID of the Facebook Cover Photo album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the facebooks' user cover photo via the PHP SDK?
Thanks in advance.

*B.W.
I have tried to loop through the Graph API, but it didn't work because the album was in the second page, and wasn't displayed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get this without looping through the album list - you could specify a higher limit in the request for the initial list of albums if you really need to do this without paginating through the albums

Comment: How can I request such a thing?(limit)

Comment: add ?limit=100 to the end of the api call to request 100 items, ?limit=200 for 200, etc